# Generic definition of back-tracking design technique

Tags: algorithm, backtracking

I am reading back tracking algorithm design technique in Introduction to Design and analysis of Algorithms by Anany Levtin.

I am having tough time in understanding generic definition of back-tracking algorithm and map it to 4 queen problem.

> For back-tracking algorithm design technique from a more general
>   perspective, most backtracking algorithms fit the following
>   description.
>
> An output of a backtracking algorithm can be thought of as an n-tuple
>   (x1, x2, x3,...,xn) where each coordinate xi is an element of some
>   finite  linearly ordered set Si. For example, for the n-queens
>   problem, each Si is the set of integers 1 through n. The tuple may
>   need to satisfy some additional constraints (e.g., the nonattacking
>   requirments in the n-queens problem).
>
> For example for 4 queen problem each Si is set {1, 2, 3, 4}
>
> A back-tracking algorithm generates explicitly or implicityly, a
>   state-space tree, its nodes represent partially constructed tuples
>   with the first "i"  coordinates defined by the earlier actions of the
>   algorithm. If such a tuple (x1, x2, x3,.. xi) is not a solution, the
>   algorithm finds the next element in Si+1 that is consistent with the
>   values of (x1, x2, x3...xi) and the problems constraints and adds it
>   to the tuple as its (i+1)st coordinate. If such an element doesnot
>   exist, the algorithm backtracks to consider the next value of xi, and
>   so on.

My questions on above text are

1. What does author mean by "A back-tracking algorithm generates explicitly or implicityly, a state-space tree, its nodes represent partially constructed tuples with the first "i" 
   coordinates defined by the earlier actions of the algorithm. If such a tuple (x1, x2, x3,.. xi) is not a solution, the algorithm finds the next element
   in Si+1 that is consistent with the values of (x1, x2, x3...xi) and the problems constraints and adds it to the tuple as its (i+1)st coordinate." ?

   To be specific what does author mean by the algorithm finds next element in Si+1?

   Kindly request to explain above statement with 4 queen problem.
2. If element does not exist the algorithm back track to consider next value of xi? Please explain this stament with 4 queen problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This explanation of backtracking is indeed hard to follow, as it uses a lot of formal notation, which is not used for a specific purpose or prove. Let me try to explain it in a less formal way with the 4-queens problem, which is an excellent example:

At the start of the backtracking process, the board is empty. This is the root of the state-space tree. This root has child nodes, one for each possibility where we could put the first queen. Rather than constructing each child node before we go to the next level (that would result in a BFS of the state-space-tree), we choose one possible position for the first queen, thereby constructing one child node. From this child node we have again multiple options to place the second queen, so we choose one, and so on.

If we arrive at the node where we have no possibilities to put a remaining queen we backtrack - we go up one level to that nodes father-node and check if there are possibilities left that we did not explore yet. If yes we explore them by creating the respective child node, if no we backtrack again, going up another level, until we either found a solution to the problem (all queens are placed) or we expanded all children of the root node and arrived at the root node during a backtrack operation - that means there is no solution.